# Remote command gives different output (permission denied)

Tags: 18.04, ssh, git

When I connect to remote server and execute command

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:repo/repo.git HEAD
```

it is working fine. But when I try to execute it from local machine as

```
ssh deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx git ls-remote git@github.com:repo/repo.git HEAD
```

it gives error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Could someone please advice why this could happen? Tried to restart ssh-agent but didn't help.

Comment: Update: I tried to add ssh key to the agent in same way and got following response:
 > ssh deploy@x.x.x.x eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 2490
> ssh deploy@x.x.x.x ssh-add /home/deploy/.ssh/github_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: When you log in to your machine, then perform the commands you want, instead of doing it all in one command, does it give the same problems?

Comment: @Sebastian, when I login to remote server and perform commands - everything is working fine. The issue happens when I invoke commands through `ssh user@server`